# Burninate "bullets"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I browsed the review queue for a moment and saw a [suggested wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2924548) for [bullets](/questions/tagged/bullets).

I wasn't sure what to do. This tag shouldn't exist, right? Can we make it go away?

Comment: Hey, I was already getting started on that :) I eventually merged it with [tag:bullet], which should also be gone.

Comment: Why not just fire the bullets :P